# Install software on CentOS VM?

Tags: linux, centos, software-installation, virtual-machine

I want to install a software (Veeam) on my CentOS 7 virtual machine, but the thing is, all I have on that VM is the shell, so there's no GUI. How can I install software on this VM? I am a newbie coming into Linux and VMs. Do I have to download and ISO file and upload it to the VM or something of the like? If so, what are the steps I'd have to do?

Comment: This question is too broad as it stands, please focus on a single, specific problem. Did you take a look at the official install guide?

Comment: Like you would on any other centos. Same tools! This is really extensively covered online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, all I had to do was download the software, upload it to my VM management site, then change the VM's CD drive to point to that ISO file.

Answer (score 0):

On your distribution, yum would probably be the first choice.

Answer (score 0):

Veeam provides a repo to install for rpm-based distributions.  Once that repo is installed, you should be able to yum search veeam and install the required components.